# Initializing an object as a 2D array then printing it

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this as my main class, which created a two-dimensional array of another class:

```
public class Tic {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    XO board[][] = new XO[3][3];
    System.out.println(board[1][1]);

   }
}
```

This is the object class being created as the 2D array:

```
public class XO {

private String name = "";

public XO() {
    name = "O";

}

public String toString() {
    return name;
    }
}
```

As you can see from the main class 'Tic', I am trying to print the 'name' variable of object board[1][1]. I expect it to print the strings 'o', but instead, it is printing null. Why is this happening when the constructor of XO is clearly setting its 'name' variable to 'o'?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `System.out.println(board[1][1].toString());` ?

Comment: you have created a 2D array of type XO, but each value of this array is still null, just as the creation of an array of int creates array with 0s. You have to make a loop that runs on this array and instantiates the actual objects (XO) inside them.

Comment: @ShadowMitia Nope, the toString method is a method from the Java library that returns something when that class is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you did was creating an array of `XO`s. But that does not initialize its child elements, that's why you were getting `null` values:

```
XO board[][] = new XO[3][3];
for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++)
        board[i][j] = new XO();

System.out.println(board[1][1]);
```

Comment: I see. I can't believe I hadn't realized this silly mistake. I'm still trying to get my head around arrays :P Thanks friend!

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in Java are by default **initialized with `null`**.

So you get a `null` or a NullPointerException when accessing it.

You will need a `for` loop if you want mutable objects.

Alternatively, you can do this (and this is probably the most elegant approach):

```
enum XO { X, O, E };
XO[][] board = new XO[][]{{E,E,E},{E,E,E},{E,E,E}};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to first give `board[1][1]` a value:

```
XO board[][] = new XO[3][3];
board[1][1] = new XO();
System.out.println(board[1][1]);
```

This should print `O` as  expected.

Answer (score 1):

The first you should add `new XO()` to array like this:

```
XO[][] board = new XO[3][3];
board[1][1] = new XO();
System.out.println(board[1][1]);
```

Because before the array was empty.

Answer (score 0):

In java, all arrays of any dimension have each cell initialised with a default value. When the array type is a primitive type, this default value is null. All numerical values are initialised to `0` (including `char`, which is initialised to `\u0000`. `boolean` arrays have every cell initialised to `false`.

Answer (score -1):

If you would like to print out the name variable, you must call your method toString().

`System.out.println(board[1][1].toString());`

Comment: Read the docs. When you call `System.out.println(OBJECT)`, it will turn it to a string first using the object's `toString()` method.

Comment: Furthermore, it will now be a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @Alex I can't believe I didn't know that.  Thanks!

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Yes, calling methods on a variable holding a null pointer will do that.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse However, `System.out.println(object)` is equivalent to `System.out.println(object == null ? "null" : object.toString()`.

Comment: That is what I'm saying. his solution makes it worse.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to Mohammed Aouf ZOUAG I was able to figure out the issue.
I have **created** the 2D array with

```
XO board[][] = new XO[3][3];
```

but I haven't **initialized** it with

```
 board[i][j] = new XO();
```

Comment: Instead of repeating his answer, accept it (but you may want to also look at the others, maybe one is more elegant).